# Looping through list and executing function

Tags: c#

I have an object model that contains several lists of other objects. I want to loop thought every object in the lists and execute a method on them. The method is called MyMethod and every object in the lists has this method in its class definition.

This is what I have:

```
public class MyObject
{
  public List<NestedObject1> ListNestedObject1 { get; set; }
  public List<NestedObject2> ListNestedObject2 { get; set; }

  public void ExecuteMethodsOfNestedObjectLists()
  {
    if (ListNestedObject1.Count > 0) { from a in ListNestedObject1 a.MyMethod();}
    if (ListNestedObject2.Count > 0) { from a in ListNestedObject2 a.MyMethod();}
  }
}
```

I'm looking to test the length of each list of nested object and execute MyMethod over each element. I know I could do a foreach loop but I want to see how to use linq syntax to keep it short.

How do I rewrite this to make it work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you're asking how to execute this method for every nested object?

```
ListNestedObject1.ForEach(obj => obj.MyMethod());
ListNestedObject2.ForEach(obj => obj.MyMethod());
```

Note: [`List.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is not LINQ(although it has a similar appearance) and was introduced in .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a foreach loop.  That's what it's for.

Linq is designed for querying data, and isn't designed to be used to cause side effects.  It seems what you're looking for is a Linq `ForEach` extension method.  Eric Lippert [explains](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx) why this was *intentionally omitted* from the language in more detail if you are interested.

You are of course free to disregard these philosophical issues and write your own `ForEach` method.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
 if (ListNestedObject1.Count > 0) { from a in ListNestedObject1 a.MyMethod(); }
```

Use

```
    if (ListNestedObject1.Count > 0)
    { 
        ListNestedObject1.Select(
        a=>
            { 
                a.MyMethod(); 
                return a;
            } 
    }
```

Replace query similarly for `ListNestedObject2`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx) extension method from `List<T>`, which is really just the same as the `foreach` loop. Note that this is not available on `IEnumerable<T>`, and in general it is highly debated whether this should be used instead of a `foreach` loop.

```
MyObject.ListNestedObject1.ForEach(MyMethod);
MyObject.ListNestedObject2.ForEach(MyMethod);
```